# accessing data response item from seperate JS file (console error)

Tags: javascript

```
Object
response: "[{"id":"28","class_id":"1463","voluntary1":"1000","voluntary2":"1000","voluntary3":"1000","assigned_risk":"1500","state":"Alabama"}]"
```

I am attempting to access `voluntary3` data above and append to my input `#input_52_22` by calling:

```
document.getElementById('#input_52_22').value= +Object.response.voluntary3;
```

But it is responding with below console error.

```
VM26293:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'voluntary3' of undefined
    at <anonymous>:1:65
```

Below is a screenshot of the response; I am simply trying to grab voluntary and append as my input id value:

[image]

I'm struggling to do this from an external file (outside of the original ajax success call, potentially this is why?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You log an object that got a `response` property, therefore it is `obj.response` not `Object.response` and it is a string, so you have to parse it:

```
JSON.parse(/*obj*/.response).voluntary3
```